# Updating a child object property of a parent object which needs to be populated in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to Mongoose and I'm having difficulty getting my head around accessing properties deeper in the model and updating properties on the following model structures.

#### Game Schema

```
var gameSchema = new Schema({
    opponents: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'teams'
    }],
    startTime: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    endTime: Date,
    pauses: [{
        start: Date,
        end: Date
    }],
    winner: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'teams'
    },
    status: {type: String, default: "created"},
    score: [{
         "opponent1": {type: Number, default: 0},
         "opponent2": {type: Number, default: 0}
    }],

}, { versionKey: false });
```

#### Team Schema

```
var teamSchema = new Schema({
    name:String,
    badge:String,
    goals:[{type: Date, default: Date.now}],
    totalWins:Number
}, { versionKey: false });
```

My problem is I'm trying to add a goal to a team from a specific game.

So my end point:

POST: **/api/game/GAME_ID/goal**

DATA: **{_id: TEAMID}**

I thought the following would work:

```
Games.findById(GAME_ID)
        .populate('opponents')
        .find({'opponent._id': TEAM_ID})
        .exec(function(err, team) {
            // Team from game with matching ID returned
            // Now push goal time into array
            team.goal.push(Date.now());
        });
```

The above does not appear to return a team. if I remove the second find the game is returned and then I have to do something horrible like this:

```
Games.findById(GAME_ID)
    .populate('opponents')
    .exec(function(err, game) {
         if(game.opponents[0]._id.toString() === req.body._id) {
             game.opponents[0].goals.push(Date.now());
         } else if (game.opponents[1]._id.toString() === req.body._id) {
             game.opponents[1].goals.push(Date.now());
         } else {
             // Throw error no matching team with id
         }
     });

game.save(function(err, game) {
    //Game saved
});
```

this last example appears to work but when I try to add further goals pushing into the goals array it overwrites the old goal time.

So to recap.

- How do I query the Games model to retrieve a child by id which has
  yet to be populated?
- How do I set push the goal time stamp into the    goals array without
  overwriting the previous one?

Is it possible to do these a bit more gracefully than the current example given above.

Answer (score 0):

```
Games.findById(GAME_ID)
    .populate(
        path: 'opponents',
        match: { _id: TEAM_ID}
    )
    .exec(function(err, team) {
        // Team from game with matching ID returned
    });
```